# How do you export tables from phpMyAdmin as plain text table format?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been through most of the export formats and can't seem to find it.

I'd like to be able to export tables visually like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262148/three-table-join-with-joins-other-than-inner-join/1262242#1262242):

```
id | name | name
----------------
1  | One  | Partridge
2  | Two  | Turtle Doves
3  | Three| French Hens
4  | Four | NULL
```

Comment: Did you want to link to the question or to the first answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262148/three-table-join-with-joins-other-than-inner-join/1262242#1262242

Answer (score 2):

That's the format you can get by running the query in command line, for instance :

```
mysql> SELECT user_ID, user_fullname FROM user;
+---------+------------------+
| user_ID | user_fullname    |
+---------+------------------+
|       1 | Marc             |
|       2 | Nicole           |
|       4 | Alexandre        |
+---------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you can access to your server that's a quick way to get this layout. Otherwise i dunno how to do it with phpMyAdmin