# Understanding LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Three table join with joins other than INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262148/three-table-join-with-joins-other-than-inner-join)

I'm a beginner in SQL and I'm trying to understand how to use the join clauses.
I used a Left Join between two tables:

```
SELECT     Table1.Key1, Table2.Key2
FROM         Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Table2 ON Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key2
```

Can I retrieve the keys who are only in the Table1 using a left Join (Or right Join)?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the Venn diagrams for the various JOIN types that Jeff Atwood posted - really quite nice and visual way to understand the JOINs!

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: +1 This link helped me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.Key1, Table2.Key2
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key2 **AND table2.otherColumn IS NULL**
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, yes - you can find out which keys are only in table1.. When they are not in table2, the table2 key is null

```
SELECT Table1.Key1, Table2.Key2
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Key1 = Table2.Key2
WHERE Table2.Key2 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I retrieve the keys who are only in the Table1 using a left Join

In common with most things in SQL, there are about seven different ways of doing this.

I find `EXCEPT` to be the simplest to understand:

```
SELECT Key1
  FROM Table1
EXCEPT 
SELECT Key2
  FROM Table2;
```